# How to concatenate two columns wrt a Key in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, concatenation

I have a table with two keys Call_ID and UUID with their respective Intent and Products. I need to concatenate the two columns with respect to UUID , such that for each UUID their would be unique intent_prouct pairs. The input and output table is given in the image

[image]

Comment: Please don't include text as images, and try to include more information regarding your question (e.g. an example query, the schema, etc). Looks like you want `GROUP BY Call_ID, UUID` combined with `STRING_AGG`, using something like the string concat to combine the two columns a la `Intent || ' ' || Product`, but this might have some weird whitespacing issues. Honestly, it's better to simply work with the proper (wrt SQL) output that is given, and to make these adjustments within your application logic.

Comment: I was thinking maybe this might work:-                                                          
SELECT Call_ID, UUID, string_agg(Intent, '_' , Product)
FROM <table_name>
GROUP BY UUID;

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: thank you , i'll keep this in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that using aggregations. ie:

```
with basedata as (
select Call_Id, UUID, max(Intent) as Intent, Max(Product) as Product
    from myTable
    group by Call_Id, UUID
)
select Call_Id, UUID, Intent || ' ' || Product as Intent_Product
from basedata;
```